# Variables not displaying on Django template

Tags: django

I have added variables to my Django views and I am trying to call them on my template. I have researched several related questions and I understand that I needed to add a context, which I believe I have done.

I am slightly confused by the use of `render()`, is this required when using generic views?

Here is an example of my view:

```
class SubgenView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'projects/subgen.html'
    context_object_name = 'subject_line_gen'
    all = {
    "first": ['Save up','New in','Huge savings',],
    "cat": ['trainers','suits','onesies'],
    "brand": ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    "third": ['at crazy prices', 'in colours galore'],
    "end": ['click now!', 'come and get it!']
    }

    first = random.choice(all['first'])

    def create_subject_parts(self):
        first = random.choice(all['first'])
        test = 'hi'
        return first
```

Adding `{{ first }}` or `{{ test }}` to my template yields nothing, what am I missing?

Comment: Try this: `from django.shortcuts import render` and then in your method `return render(request, self.template_name, {'first':first})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context in generic views is generated by `get_context_data`.

In your case it would be

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["first"] = ['Save up','New in','Huge savings',]
    context["cat"] = ['trainers','suits','onesies']
    context["brand"] = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    context["third"] = ['at crazy prices', 'in colours galore']
    context["end"] = ['click now!', 'come and get it!']
    return context
```

There is no need to call or modify `render` in generic views, unless you are changing default behavior.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense but values are still not rendering on the template. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Got it, I renamed the function, not realizing that it *had* to be called `get_context_data`.